# How can I delete an entry on Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

How can I delete an entry on Cognito Forms?
I mean, it is that possible?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Do you mean you've filled out and submitted data on a form and you want to remove it? Or that you've created a form and you want to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

To delete a specific entry in Cognito Forms:

1. Select the entry from the entries list on the Entries page.
2. Once the specific entry has been selected, it will expand to show the entry’s details.
3. Clicking the Delete button at the bottom of the page will open a dialog where you will need to confirm the entry’s deletion.

Please note: Once you delete an entry, its data will be permanently deleted and you will not be able to retrieve it.